# Difference between gcc compile options std=c++1y and std=c++14

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I installed gcc 4.9.2. I compiled the program using the following command:

```
/root/gcc-4.9.2/bin/g++ -std=c++1y testing.cpp
```

Note that in addition to the option `-std=c++1y`, there is another option `-std=c++14`. Will the compiler work in the same way and generate exactly the same executable for both options?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-108

Comment: Thanks limecore for the explanation and thanks Marc for the link which states that c++1y and c++14 are "The 2014 ISO C++ standard plus amendments. The name ‘c++1y’ is deprecated. "

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`C++ 14` is the latest ISO standard, and should be used unless you need some gcc non standard feature.

`c++1y` is a name that was used to refer to the c++14 standard before it was completed, so it is most likely adhering to a draft of the standard, but not the actual standard itself. There may be some minute differences between the two, but `c++14` is the ISO standard.

In short, use `c++14`.

Answer (score 6):

In case of gcc 4.9.2 mentioned by you there is no difference between `c++14` and `c++1y`. But for the earlier gcc version, e.g. gcc 4.8.1 there is [no `c++14` option](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Me6MdGOhFTalBsIk)

> ```
> g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14'
> ```

because the year of standard acceptance was not known yet. In such cases using the `-std=c++1y` option is [only solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6sqaTqboRDvmHZ02) to enable some parts of oncoming c++14 standard.